# What is the best practice to serialize `User` model for guest and authrized user specified by JSONAPI?

Tags: express, serialization, ember.js, sequelize.js, json-api

I'm building API with `express.js` according to JSONAPI specification and have `sequelize.js` model. For example, `User` model with attributes such as name, email, balance, last_login_time and etc.

If user on client application request data about third-party user API needs to respond only with public attributes such as name and last_login_time.

If user on client application request data about himself API needs to respond with public and private attributes.

As a serializer I use [`jsonapi-serializer`](https://github.com/SeyZ/jsonapi-serializer) lib. I have serializer like that:

```
var JSONAPISerializer = require('jsonapi-serializer').Serializer;

module.exports = new JSONAPISerializer('users', {
  attributes: ['name']
});
```

Sould I create 2 different serializer? Will not it lead to troubles because almost all models will have 2 serializers and it could lead to confusion of references?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `instanceMethod` like so:

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    ...
    instanceMethods: {
        serializeApi: function () {
            return User.apiSerializer().serialize(this);
        }
    }
};

User.apiSerializer = function() {
    return new JSONAPISerializer('users', {
        attributes: ['name']
    });
}
```

.

```
User.find(...).then((user) => {
    res.json(user.serializeApi());
});
```

Comment: Your approach is good. But my problem how to serialize some additional attributes for authorized user, for example, when he fetches his profile data?

Comment: is it good way move `email` field from `user` to `user.profile`?